# Ionic2: How to change the default push animation of Navigation Controller with NavOptions?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a list on a view and each item of the list when clicked renders a new view. I want it to be sliding from the right edge of the screen like in default android (I assume). The default NavControl.push() method in Ionic2 renders the new view like it appears out of no where. From the [Ionic2 docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#navoptions), it is mentioned obscurely that, this may be possible (but no examples are given). From the docs regarding NavOptions,

> Some methods on NavController allow for customizing the current transition. To do this, we can pass an object with the modified properites.
>
> The property 'animation' understands the following values: md-transition, ios-transition and wp-transition.

Can anyone explain how this NavOptions is used to change the animation of NavController.push()?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use :

```
 var navOptions = {
      animation: 'ios-transition'
 };
 this.navController.push(NewPage, null, navOptions);
```

Comment: Sorry but this didn't change anything. Same animation as before.

Comment: Just found out that this works only if the value of 'animation' is changed to 'ios-transition' instead of 'md-transition' or 'wp-transition'. Please change your answer to approve.

Comment: How could this be accomplished with the Modal Controller?

Comment: Open another question if you want help ;-)

Comment: how define it in java?